# Where is the section handler of Elmah

Tags: elmah

In the web.config, there is the declare of the Elmah section.

```
<section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
```

This means that the class of Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler will handle the section information.
But I opened the Elmah.dll and tried to find this class. I can't find this class in the assembly. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because it is marked as `internal`.  See the source code from the [Elmah repository](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/src/Elmah/?r=f9272c55dcfd0f6f09249719529c0f3e075502c2) for [SecuritySectionHandler.cs](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/src/Elmah/SecuritySectionHandler.cs?r=f9272c55dcfd0f6f09249719529c0f3e075502c2).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am also wondering maybe the key word of internal is the matter. Do you have more information about why the interal class cannot be seen from assembly.dll?